# delete pathc put symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony

Есть пустой проект без фреймворка, но со скачанным `symfony/router`. Вот сам роутинг:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->add('contacts_all', new Route('/api/v1/contacts', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::index']));
$routes->add('contact_show', new Route('/api/v1/contacts/{contact}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::show']));
$routes->add('contact_delete', new Route('/api/v1/contacts/{contact}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::delete'], [], [], '', ['DELETE']));
$routes->add('api_v1', new Route('/api/{any}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\AppController::errorApi'], ['any' => '.*']));

$routes->add('index', new Route('/', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\AppController::index']));
$routes->add('any', new Route('/{any}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\AppController::index'], ['any' => '.*']));

return $routes;
```

Не работает метод DELETE, в чем может быть ошибка?

PS: вообще есть решение у меня, но оно мне не нравится:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

$routes = new RouteCollection();

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    case 'GET':
        $routes->add('contacts_all', new Route('/api/v1/contacts', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::index']));
        $routes->add('contact_show', new Route('/api/v1/contacts/{contact}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::show']));
        $routes->add('api_v1', new Route('/api/{any}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\AppController::errorApi'], ['any' => '.*']));
        $routes->add('index', new Route('/', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\AppController::index']));
        $routes->add('any', new Route('/{any}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\AppController::index'], ['any' => '.*']));
        break;
    case 'DELETE':
        $routes->add('contact_delete', new Route('/api/v1/contacts/{contact}', ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::delete']));
        break;
}

return $routes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Поскольку в предыдущих роутах явно не указан метод, то принимается любой. И роут `contact_show` срабатывает и на GET и на DELETE, поскольку паттерн одинаковый. Поднимите роут `contact_delete` выше чем `contact_show` или явно пропишите в `contact_show` метод GET
2. У вас пропущен один параметр. Перед `['DELETE']` вставьте еще один пустой массив

> Defining Routes
>
> A full route definition can contain up to eight parts:
>
> ```
> $route = new Route(
>     '/archive/{month}', // path
>     ['_controller' => 'showArchive'], // default values
>     ['month' => '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}', 'subdomain' => 'www|m'], // requirements
>     [], // options
>     '{subdomain}.example.com', // host
>     [], // schemes
>     [], // methods
>     'context.getHost() matches "/(secure|admin).example.com/"' // condition
> );
> ```

```
$routes->add('contact_delete', new Route(
    '/api/v1/contacts/{contact}', //path
    ['_controller' => 'Controllers\ContactController::delete'], //default values
    [], // requirements
    [], // options
    '', // host
    ['DELETE'] // !!! sсhemes
));
```

Comment: неа, это я проверял тоже, результата 0

Comment: а не срабатывает вообще или срабатывает другое правило?

Comment: работают только геты, что по умолчанию

Comment: я имею в виду, что на DELETE срабатывает GET? Или на DELETE ошибка no route?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Наверное проблема в этом